# I can`t update the table in apex 5.0.2 if there is more than 1 row in the table

Tags: oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4jDH.png)I need help, I created an application in Apex 5.0.2, created a tabular form, I'm trying to update the table, if there is only one row in the table, then everything is fine, updates, but if there is more than one row: in Ora-01403: no data found(row 2).
Debugger:
...Check authorization security schemes

...Initialize tabular form column mapping

Session State: Save form items and p_arg_values

Processes - point: ON_SUBMIT_BEFORE_COMPUTATION

Branch point: Before Computation

Process point: AFTER_SUBMIT

Tabs: Perform Branching for Tab Requests

Branch point: Before Validation

Validations:

Perform basic and predefined validations:

Perform custom validations:

Branch point: Before Processing

Processes - point: AFTER_SUBMIT

...Process "ApplyMRU" - Type: NATIVE_TABFORM_UPDATE

Logging exception:
Sqlerrm: ORA-01403: No data found
Backtrace: ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ITEM", line 2802

Add error onto error stack

...Error data:

......message: ORA-01403: данные не найдены

......additional_info: ORA-01403: данные не найдены

......display_location: INLINE_IN_NOTIFICATION

......association_type: REGION

......region_id: 6926785905782833

......row_num: 2

......is_internal_error: false

......ora_sqlcode: 100

......ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: No data found

......error_backtrace: ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ITEM", line 2802

......component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS

......component.id: 6931335874782845

......component.name: ApplyMRU

Logging exception:
Sqlerrm: User-Defined Exception
Backtrace: ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 635
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ITEM", line 3058
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ITEM", line 3730
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 451
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1130
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2014
ORA-06512: на  "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 188

Show current page with inline errors

R E Q U E S T show

I tried to create other tables, tried to change the key from rowid to rn. The error does not change.If there is more than 1 row, then NO DATA FOUND appears.

Comment: It isn't internal error, which means that exception is raised by your own code. Debugger says it is associated to region_id 6926785905782833. How many regions do you have on that page? Review **all** SELECT statements you have. Also, is there - by any chance - database **trigger** (on table associated to tabular form) which might have raised the error?

Comment: On a side note: tabular forms are no longer available in later versions of apex. The strength of apex is that applications live for a long time (and many releases). I'd reconsider using a tabular form, upgrade and use interactive grid.

Comment: I would like to do this, but there is no interactive grid in version 5.0.2

Comment: Regarding @Koen's *side note*: true, they don't exist any more (i.e. you can't create such a region), but applications - that have pages with tabular forms regions - still work. How do I know? I have them!